# 9 errors when the blank xamarin Forms Application is build

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I am using visual studio 2015, with Xamarin forms Android version 2.4.0.280. Target Framework and Target Android Version are set to Androide 6.0. JDK, Android SDK, NDK locations are properly set.

It gives following 9 errors when the blank xamarin Forms Application is build.

> .1. Error No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'. App5.Android c:\users\abhiram behera\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App5\App5\App5.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml 2
>   2. Error No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'. App5.Android c:\users\abhiram behera\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App5\App5\App5.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml 2
>   3. Error No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'. App5.Android c:\users\abhiram behera\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App5\App5\App5.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml 2
>   4. Error No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'. App5.Android c:\users\abhiram behera\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App5\App5\App5.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml 2
>   5. Error Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'. App5.Android c:\users\abhiram behera\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App5\App5\App5.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml 2
>   6. Error No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'. App5.Android c:\users\abhiram behera\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App5\App5\App5.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml 3
>   7. Error No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'. App5.Android c:\users\abhiram behera\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App5\App5\App5.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml 4
>   8. Error No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionModeOverlay'. App5.Android c:\users\abhiram behera\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App5\App5\App5.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml 4
>   9. Error Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'. App5.Android c:\users\abhiram behera\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App5\App5\App5.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml 4

Please tell me what may be possible errors in setting configuration?

Comment: First of all, Please close your VS, then delete all of the `bin` and `obj` folders in your project folder. Rebuild your project. If this issue is still existed. Xamarin forms version 2.4.0.280 is too old. It pushlised at 9/27/2017, please update your nuget packages to the latest. And set the android Target Framework and Target Android Version to the (Android 8.0) or higher.

Comment: For visual Studio 2015, it allows this as the latest update. As per your advice I will go for Android 8.0. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I am using Xamarin Forrms 4.4; But its Android Version is written as 2.4.0.280.

Comment: use VS2019 for best compatibility and dev experience with Xamarin Forms

Comment: Did you try to delete  all of the bin and obj folders in your project folder. Rebuild your project, if this issue is disappear.

Comment: @AbhiramBehera : I think that you can resolve these Errors by Updating All the packages in Xamarin.Android Project and than Restart your Solution , Remove Bin and Obj and Run Application.

FYI,: Please use VS 2019 for best compatibility.

Comment: there is no bin and obj folder in the project

Comment: there is no bin and obj folder

Comment: Ok ,as Krunal said, did you try to use VS 2019 and update all of your nuget packages to the latest.